# How do I make an offline front end for over 50 pdf documents?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I have over 50 training documents (PDFs) at work. I would like to create a 'front end' that a user can 'run', which would provide a convenient access portal to all the PDFs available.

This needs to be able to be dropped on to my work colleagues laptops (they don't have Office on there but do have Acrobat). And it also needs to be able to be edited/added to as more PDF training materials are created.

I know that I could create a Word document that contained links to the PDFs, then convert that to a PDF itself. Or I could create an offline web page that linked to them, but I wondered if there was a better solution?

Like a way to compile an executable that would bring up a front-end and contain all the PDF files? I've seen similar things for car-repair manuals years ago, where you insert a CD, run an executable and get a nice front-end that essentially just allows you to browse PDF manuals.

Anyone know if this is possible and, if so, how to go about it?

Or does anyone know another viable solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed various possibilities, depending on what the users have (Acrobat or Reader), and how you can control the distribution.

a) You create a front end PDF document which has links or buttons to open the subsequent documents residing in a subfolder or on the same level as the front end document.

b) You create a front end PDF document into which you embed the subsequent documents as Data Objects. You have buttons which export/open the embedded documents in a different window.

c) You create a front end PDF document into which you embed the subsequent documents as File Attachments (part of the Comments tools). You have buttons which open the embedded documents.

d) You would create a PDF Portfolio in Acrobat, containing the subsequent documents, and maybe provide an overview page from which you can open the documents.

Of these three approaches, a) would run in the biggest number of supporting PDF viewers, in particular also mobile devices. The downside is that you have the subsequent documents around loosely, and your users may mess up with them.

The most elegant (and app-like) approach would be b). However, it requires smart PDF viewers, and you would have to make sure that the user's viewer is not too dumb.

Approach c) would be a compromise between integrity and portability, and approach d) would be quite nice for distributing, but does require a PDF viewer by Adobe, and may most likely not work in any mobile viewer.

Comment: Thanks for that comprehensive answer. I think d) would be the right approach for me. These will only be viewed on laptops and not on mobile devices. I've never made a PDF portfolio but will look into it on Monday. I have the pro version of Acrobat 9 so hopefully the functionality will be in there. Thanks again :-)

Comment: That's an approach, and thanks for the response. One little note: you may verify if the Portfolios created in Acrobat 9 will properly work in Reader DC. They should, but there have been some changes between the versions, and I am not sure whether you would be affected.